# $.post not working when element dropped

Tags: php, jquery

I'm teaching myself jQuery and PHP and I'm having a few problems. I need the element id to be posted to my php script once dropped over my droppable div. The following code does not post when I drag and drop an element over a droppable div. I have tried the following:

- I have removed everything apart from an alert box to check that an item has been dropped which it does, so the item is being seen as droppable!.
- I have entered some content into the div manually to ensure results can been seen
- I have replaced name to var name="test", to test the varible contents.

The javascript file and the php script reside in the same directory, file names are correct. The javascript drag and drop script is included after droppable area

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/drag-drop.js"></script>
```

I have replaced the result of php script as plain text to see if the problem could be the variable received, nothing returns. So the post does not seem to be getting to the php script. Hope someone can provide a few pointers!

Below is my code, the HTML is just a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#carousel-ul li').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: true
    });

    $('#drop').droppable({ 
        hoverClass: 'drophover',
        accept: '#carousel-ul li',
        drop: function(){
            //alert("has been accepted and dropped");
            var name = ui.helper.attr('id').val();
            $.post('javascript.php', { name: name }, function(data){
                $('#drop-content').html(data);
            });
        }           
    });           
});

<?php
    //echo "id was posted";
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name =  $_POST['name'];
        var_dump($name);
        echo name;
        //echo "id was posted inside";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `echo name;` should be `echo $name;` - or is that just a typo?

Comment: I guess the alert is actually working when uncommenting it? In that case nothing is wrong with your drop event function. Have you checked if the post is actually sent? (use ie. google developer tools in chrome for that; ctrl+shift+i, checkout the 'Network' tab). What does it say?

Comment: You are calling `.val()` after `.attr('id')`. You shouldn't do that. `.val()` is a convenience method for `.attr('value')`, but you're calling it on a string (the id) instead of an element, and `.attr('id')` is all you need to do to get the ID of the element. Edit: Also, you should probably change `drop: function()` to `drop: function(event, ui)`, as right now, you're calling an undefined variable (ui).

Comment: Great tool giorgio going to use this in future thanks for that ;) I have found that even tho I thought php script was in correct place it was not so I moved this. I get under console outputs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined so could be the variable, I changed to just a string and it seems to work so the problem seems to be on the var name line, any ideas as to what this could be

Comment: This now works hovever posts the id not the contents of id as defined in my php code id="'.$thumbImage.'" any ideas? thats why I tried val()

Answer (score 0):

The [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) for the Droppable widget says that the `ui` parameter is a jQuery object, so you should try something like this:

```js
$('#drop').droppable({ 
    hoverClass: 'drophover',
    accept: '#carousel-ul li',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var name = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
        var content = $(ui.helper).html();
        $.post('javascript.php', { name: name, content: content }, function(data) {
            $('#drop-content').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```